# json array without null values in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT
    post.post_id,
    ARRAY_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('id', post_media_id, 'type', post_media.type)) as medias
FROM post
LEFT OUTER JOIN post_media 
    ON post_media.post_id = post.post_id
GROUP BY
    post.post_id
```

I want the output to be empty array or null if media doesn't exist but I get this if not exist

```
 [{
   id:null,
   type:null
}]
```

so I tried to use this

```
ARRAY_REMOVE(ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN post_media_id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('id',post_media_id,'type',post_media.type) END),null) as medias,
```

but I got this error:

> 'could not identify an equality operator for type json'

Comment: Please show us some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Why do you want an array of JSON objects and not a JSON array?

Comment: The error "*could not identify an equality operator for type json*" can be avoided by using `jsonb` instead of `json`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample input data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. (please [edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `jsonb`, which has an equality operator, and a `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(
          jsonb_build_object(
             'id', post_media_id,
             'type', post_media.type
          )
       ) FILTER (WHERE coalesce(post_media_id, post_media.type) IS NOT NULL)
...
```

That will omit all elements where both `post_media_id` and `post_media.type` are NULL from the aggregate.

Comment: I need output to be null or empty array not [null]

Comment: It is not obvious what you want. I have changed the answer, perhaps I guessed right this time.